# Mounting Remote Server for editing files on my Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, mount

My web development server is in the Cloud and I am very new to Macs.

On Ubuntu and other flavors of Linux, I would mount the remote drives using sshfs. I have researched SSHFS for Mac and come up with **FUSE for OS x** and **MacFUSE**. I have them both installed but when I attempt to run *man sshfs* on my commandline I get a command not found error.

Unless I am missing something, I can't find simple instructions to help me resolve this issue.

I have tried **Mount** and **Mount_smbfs** too but I immediately get *server connection failed: operation timed out* errors.

My Mac runs on OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

Can anyone please give me some simple steps to help overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't want to have both MacFUSE and FUSE for OS X (OSXFUSE) installed, OSXFUSE is a replacement for MacFUSE, which is no longer under active development.

OSXFUSE is not an application, it is a kernel extension and libraries that allow developers to easily write a file system that lives in user space rather than in the kernel. Once you have it installed you need to then install a file system, in your case sshfs, which can be found on the OSXFUSE website (http://osxfuse.github.io/).

Once you have both OSXFUSE and sshfs installed then you still won't have a Mac application, but you will have a command line tool `sshfs`in `/usr/local/bin` and a `man sshfs` at the command line will give you the manual page for it.

If you would like a GUI then you can install Macfusion (http://macfusionapp.org/) and follow the instructions here (https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS#macfusion) so that it uses the much more reliable OSXFUSE version of sshfs rather than the MacFUSE based one it ships with.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the software might not be installed the right way, or in the right place.  On a Mac, the easiest way to install sshfs and fuse is with Homebrew.

1. Install Homebrew http://brew.sh/
2. `brew install sshfs`

   This will install dependencies such as fuse4x.  Read all the instructions that appear -- some of other steps may be required, such as

   `brew link fuse4x`
   `sudo /bin/cp -rfX /usr/local/Cellar/fuse4x-kext/0.9.2/Library/Extensions/fuse4x.kext /Library/Extensions`
   `sudo chmod +s /Library/Extensions/fuse4x.kext/Support/load_fuse4x`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed **Fuse for OSX** you will find the binary you are searching at `/Applications/Macfusion.app/Contents/PlugIns/sshfs.mfplugin/Contents/Resources/sshfs-static`.

You can use `ln -s [Path-like-above] [Your-favorit-bin-path]/sshfs` if you want to call it with `sshfs`.

If you get a `command not found` error and not a `No manual entry for sshfs`, then `man` is not found and this indicates no issue with **sshfs**.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Dor. Whilest I can see FUSE for OS x clearly installed in the System Preference area, I can't navigate to it via the command line. It just lists all the other applications except for FUSE OS X